# How to avoid background tab throttling for an HTML5 radio app?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, websocket, html5-audio

I am running an internet [radio station](https://coderadio.freecodecamp.org/) that uses an html5 audio element and a websocket.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API#policies_in_place_to_aid_background_page_performance) browsers should not throttle tabs that play audio or use websockets; however when the radio app runs in a background tab, connection drops in less than 30 minutes (the delay depends on the device's RAM and load) with the following error:

`GET https://coderadio-relay-blr.freecodecamp.org/radio/8010/radio.mp3 net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED 200`

Note1: The app optimizes for tab visibility and reduces its memory usage when it is in a background tab.

Note2: A similar behavior is experienced when a [simple html5 audio and vanilla JS is used](https://codepen.io/abdolsa/pen/dyVdgNM).

Note3: Here is the [source code](https://github.com/freeCodeCamp/coderadio-client).

Note4: The experience is similar across browsers.